# Use Capistrano to deploy production and development environments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I have setup Capistrano to deploy my rails app on the production server, this is working fine.

I now need to be able to deploy the same app on a development server. To do this I have created 2 tasks in the config.deploy.rb:

```
desc "Run on development server" 
task :dev do 
  server "development_server", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
end 

desc "Run on production server" 
task :production do 
  server "production_server", :web, :app, :db, :primary => true
end
```

Doing so, to perfom the deployment on dev, I need to isuse:

cap dev deploy

But, I do not manage to tell Capitrano to run the bundle on the correct env, it uses the "--without development test" option where I would need to have "--without test production"

```
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3' -c 'cd /var/be/releases/20120824155742 && bundle install --gemfile /var/be/releases/20120824155742/Gemfile --path /var/be/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on 192.168.1.10
```

Any idea how to perform this ?

Also, how can I selectively start thin in development or production env ? Do I need to create a task for each one or is there any special way of doing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the Capistrano Multistage extension. [This Wiki](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension) will explain much better then I could how it is used. The only problem I had, which was small, was figuring out that with:`require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'` the `require 'capistrano'` was not needed.